# Are there tools available to convert SMT-LIB files to DIMACS CNF?

Tags: z3, smt, sat

I'm using the [MONOSAT](https://github.com/sambayless/monosat) SMT solver for graphs which only accepts [.gnf files](https://github.com/sambayless/monosat/blob/master/FORMAT.md) (an extension of DIMACS CNF with a way to specify graph nodes/edges) or input through its Python API. However, the input files I want to test for satisfiability are written in the SMT-LIB format. Are there tools to convert between the two formats?

For instance, it is my understanding that the [Z3 solver](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) supports input from both SMT-LIB and DIMACS and has respective parsers in the source code for these formats. Is there anything else that would work on its own to convert an SMT problem?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such tool. "Tool recommendations" is usually out-of-scope for stack-overflow, so this question might end up getting closed. In any case, it'd be best to contact MONOSAT developers and ask them directly.